# Is it possible to communicate with the iOS Google Maps app via Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, bluetooth

I would like to tell the Google Maps app destination coordinates and afterwards receive the current coordinates via Bluetooth. Is this possible somehow or do I need to write my own app for that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? connect the phone to your bluetooth audio?

Comment: No, I have an external micro-controller with Bluetooth which should use the destination coordinates from Google Maps, so e.g. when I search for a place on my smartphone and Google Maps computes a route, I would like to receive the angle to the destination on my micro-controller-device every few seconds to build an external display visualizing the route (only angle to destination needed).

Comment: Probably there is not such a concept in iOS and I have to write my own app with Google Maps API…

Comment: Answer to your question is Yes. You can do it and yes you would have to create your own app. But you need to look into what Bluetooth profiles do the iphone devices you are targeting can handle and what Bluetooth profiles can your controller handle. This question should therefore be more relevant in terms of core Bluetooth engineering.

Comment: At this stage you should first find out how (if at all) you can establish a proper Bluetooth communication between both devices. Writing an application will come later. Something to start with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Basic_Imaging_Profile_.28BIP.29 ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange

Comment: I will use a [BLE Nano](http://redbearlab.com/blenano/). There is an example chat-app (over Bluetooth) which works with iPhone 4S, so I already now, that this shouldn’t be a problem.